# How to consume html data returned as a string variable from a REST webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Hi i am new to REST web services, as far as i have read from tutorials online i have been successful in making a simple project which returns a simple hard coded string and i am able to get the data also from the client that i have developed, but now i am trying to fetch some data from database and storing it in a string variable in the form of html tags something like

```
String details=details = "<html><body>"; 
details = details + "<table border=1>";
details = details + "<tr><td><Strong>Id </Strong></td>" +
                            "<td><Strong>Name </Strong></td>" + "</tr>";

    while(rs.next())  
    {
        details = details + "<tr><td>" + rs.getInt("ID") + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + rs.getString("NAME") + "</td></tr>";
    } 

    details += "</table></body></html>"
```

but now the problem i am facing is that i am not able to retrieve the same values. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The webservice that i have made is like the following:

```
package bhavya.ws;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;


import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//@WebService
@Path("/database")
public class DatabaseStorage {

@GET
@Path("/fetch")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String fetchFromDB()
{
    String data="";
    DbConnection connection = new DbConnection();
    data=connection.fetchFromDB();
    System.out.println("data is :" +data);
    return data;

}
}
```

The method fetchFromDB is like following:

```
package bhavya.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DbConnection {
public String fetchFromDB()
{
    String details=null;

try 
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE","system","password");  

    //step3 create the statement object  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

    //step4 execute query  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from data"); 

    details = "<html><body>"; 
    details = details + "<table border=1>";
    details = details + "<tr><td><Strong>Id </Strong></td>" +
                            "<td><Strong>Name </Strong></td>" + "</tr>";

    while(rs.next())  
    {
        details = details + "<tr><td>" + rs.getInt("ID") + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + rs.getString("NAME") + "</td></tr>";
    } 

    details += "</table></body></html>";

    //step5 close the connection object  
    con.close();      
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
System.out.println("details is :"+details);
return details;
}
}
```

And the client class that i have written is like the following:

```
package bhavya.ws;

import java.net.URI;  
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;  
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;  
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;  

public class HelloClientRest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();  
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);  
    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());  
    //Now printing the server code of different media type  
   // System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("hello").path("/plain").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));  
   // System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class));  
    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("database").path("fetch").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class));  
  }  
  private static URI getBaseURI() {  
    //here server is running on 4444 port number and project name is restfuljersey  
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8081/REST_JERSEY_WS_SERVER").build();  
  }  

}
```

Now the problem is that in the webservice class if i replaced the variable data with the hard coded string like this:

```
return "<h1>hello</h1>";
```

The client code gives me correct output, but if i return variable data i dint get any output.

i want the data in the variable data to be sent as a html string to my client.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then your variable probably stays null, because you have an exception before initializing it, and are ignoring it. Print the stack trace of the exception (or better, throw it from your method), check your server logs, use your debugger.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i am running the same program from main and its giving me the proper output, hence i am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have successfully wired my program, it was sort of a silly mistake on my side as i was not making the sql jar file in the web app library, hence my code was not able to load the values from the database.

Solved the same after putting the jar ojdbc.jar in the lib folder in WEB-INF solved the problem, and as far as what i said about the functioning being successful with the main program, it was because in a stand alone app, it is not required to add jar in lib, only adding to build path would do the work.